# Git alias for git status lists files relative to repository root

Tags: git

I have a bunch of shorthand aliases for git commands. One of them is `git stat` as an abbreviation for `git status`.

I declare the alias in my global git configuration (living in `~/.gitconfig`) as

```
[alias]
stat = !"git status"
```

This works fine but an annoying problem occurs: When I'm inside of a git repository `git stat` always shows me paths relative to the repository root rather than to the current directory.

An example:

```
repo
├── .git
└── folder
    └── file
```

```
$ cd repo/folder
$ touch fileB
$ git stat
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    folder/fileB
$ git status
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    fileB
```

As you can see `git stat` lists `fileB` relative to `repo` while `git status` lists it relative to `repo/folder`.

How can I achieve my alias to behave as the original command?

Comment: Why is your `!` outside of the double quotes? Maybe unrelated, but odd. And it's also unneeded, `stat = "status"` is fine (and almost useless.... gain 2 keystrokes?)

Comment: Hm, honestly don't know but doesn't change anything. Regarding the uselessness: Where to you put the line? I think `stat` is rather readable but a bit shorter, so why not.

Comment: @RomainValeri: indeed, unrelated: you can enter and exit double quotes wherever you like, as needed. The shell works the same way, which means there's a simple way to quote text for `sh`: use single quotes for everything, and then if you need a single quote, exit single quotes briefly, use `\'` once, and re-enter single quotes: `echo 'He said, "Hello, don'\''t I know you?"'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You registered your alias as an external shell command (starting with `!`), which will be run from the repo's root.

If you want a shortcut for known git commands, set a simple alias rule :

```
git config --global alias.stat status
```

This also works with options to git commands :

```
git config --global alias.stat "status -sb"
```

You will gain the bonus ability to autocomplete all known options to this command (since git now "understands" what the alias is).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

You're running into the fact that aliased shell commands are run from the top level of the working tree.  This *is* documented, but it's cleverly hidden in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), since there is no better place to put it:

> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it
> will be treated as a shell command. For example, defining `alias.new = !gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD`, the invocation `git new` is equivalent
> to running the shell command `gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD`. Note that
> shell commands will be executed from the top-level directory of a
> repository, which may not necessarily be the current directory.
> `GIT_PREFIX` is set as returned by running `git rev-parse --show-prefix` from the original current directory. See [git-rev-
> parse[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse).

You can use `$GIT_PREFIX` to locate the target directory.  In this particular case, though, [LeGEC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69016879/1256452), pointing to using a simple alias, is the way to go.